# Apply np.vectorize along one axis

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say I have two arrays `arr1` and `arr2`:

```py
arr1 = [0, 1, 2]

arr2 = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
]
```

And say I have a function that does something to the elements of this array:

```py
def func(arr):
    new_arr = arr.copy()
    new_arr[0] = new_arr[0] * 2
    new_arr[1] = new_arr[1] * 10
    new_arr[2] = new_arr[2] * 100
    return new_arr
```

Now I want to vectorize this, so that it works for both `arr1` and `arr2`:

```py
func(arr1)
# returns [0, 10, 200]
func(arr2)
# returns
# [0, 10, 200],
# [6, 40, 500],
# [12, 70, 800],
```

`np.vectorize` doesn't work because it breaks down each and every element in my array parameter. I want it to apply the function only along the first axis.

`np.apply_along_axis` almost works, except it won't consider 1-D array parameter to be a single parameter.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: vectorize and apply are not performance tools.  If they don't work for you, do something else.  Even a nested loop is better.

Comment: Don't be afraid test the number of dimensions, and change `arr1` into a (1,3) shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take time to read the `np.vectorize` docs, you'll eventually encounter the `signature` option:

```
In [27]: f= np.vectorize(func, signature='(n)->(n)')
In [28]: f(arr1)
Out[28]: array([  0,  10, 200])
In [29]: f(arr2)
Out[29]: 
array([[  0,  10, 200],
       [  6,  40, 500],
       [ 12,  70, 800]])
```

And reading a bit further you'll encounter the caveats about performance.

Comment: An excellent answer. In the more general case, where one might want to vectorize a function to operate on two vectors given a 2D array input (an m x n matrix) and another vector (n), the following would seem to work `signature='(n,m),(n)->(m)'` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just directly multiply the arrays. It works thanks to [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
factor = np.array([2, 10, 100])

arr1 * factor
array([  0,  10, 200])

arr2 * factor
array([[  0,  10, 200],
       [  6,  40, 500],
       [ 12,  70, 800]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2])

b = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
])

c = np.array([2, 10, 100])

print(a*c)

print(b*c)
```

Output:

```
[  0  10 200]
[[  0  10 200]
 [  6  40 500]
 [ 12  70 800]]
```